# Progress Bar Fill Up Bottom-To-Top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have a progress bar. With simple colors, it works perfectly. When I put in images, it filles top-to-bottom, not bottom-to-top, and I don't know how to fix it. Help?

http://jsfiddle.net/Aiphira/1k8sddvq/

```
    <div id="load-form">
    <div class="load-line"></div>
</div>
<center>
<div class="percent"></div>
<div class="asd">2000</div>
</center>



$(document).ready(function(e) {

            var maxonline = 6000;
            var currentonline = $(this).find('.asd').html();
            var percent = currentonline/maxonline*100;
            if(percent > 100)
                percent = 100;
            if(currentonline > maxonline) {
                alert('Its full');
                return;
            }
            $('.load-line').animate({height: percent+'%' },500);
            $('.percent').html(percent+'%')

    });



#load-form { width:137px; height:87px; background:url('http://la2portal.us.lt/status_online_simple.png'); margin:100px auto 0;  position:relative; } 
#load-form .load-line { background:url('http://la2portal.us.lt/status_online_full.png'); height:0; width:137px; bottom:4px; left:6px; max-height:87px;}
```

Comment: `center` has been deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: you forgot position:absolute; i believe  http://jsfiddle.net/1k8sddvq/2/ and yes center tag  is obsolete ;) ... there is even a progress tag in html5 spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute positioning and background positioning is required to do this kind of thing. Add these

```
#load-form .load-line {
    position: absolute;
    background: url('http://la2portal.us.lt/status_online_full.png') no-repeat bottom;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var maxonline = 6000;
    var currentonline = $(this).find('.asd').html();
    var percent = currentonline/maxonline*100;
    if(percent > 100)
        percent = 100;
    if(currentonline > maxonline) {
        alert('Its full');
        return;
    }
    $('.load-line').animate({height: percent+'%' },500);
    $('.percent').html(percent+'%')

});
```

```css
#load-form {
    width: 137px;
    height: 87px;
    background: url('http://la2portal.us.lt/status_online_simple.png');
    margin: 100px auto 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#load-form .load-line {
    position: absolute;
    background: url('http://la2portal.us.lt/status_online_full.png') no-repeat bottom;
    height: 0px;
    width: 137px;
    bottom: 0px;
    max-height: 87px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="load-form">
    <div class="load-line"></div>
</div>
<center>
    <div class="percent"></div>
    <div class="asd">2000</div>
</center>
```

As others have noted, `center` has been deprecated and its use is discouraged. (Had to include that for anyone who might end up here and didn't look at the comments.)

Comment: It doesn't work the way I want it to. In the first post/link, when you go there, you see it fills up from top to bottom (green color). However, when I do it this way (with absolute etc.), the whole image moves. I need it so it reveals, just like it does now, just that it would be from bottom-up not from top-down.

Comment: Strange. I'm sorry. I swear I just had it working. I'll get back on it.

Comment: @Aiphira: I was working in jsfiddle, copied it over to a snippet and forgot to add the jQuery. Check it now. I did have to make a few minor CSS changes aside from what I listed to position it correctly too.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```
.load-form, .load-line{
  vertical-align:bottom
}
```

Option 2:

```
.load-line{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work the way I want it to. In the first post/link, when you go there, you see it fills up from top to bottom (green color). However, when I do it this way (with absolute etc.), the whole image moves. I need it so it reveals, just like it does now, just that it would be from bottom-up not from top-down.

Comment: @Aiphira You can try playing with  `background-position` css with `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

I manipulated your code a bit, check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptpm6ktk/).

Not sure if that's the way to go, this is a kind of a workaround.

What I did was to set the value first to `0`, and then to `100 - %`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think he wants the green filling in from the bottom to the top

Comment: no, it's the gray coming up from the bottom instead of the green coming up from the bottom is what i'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

i tried a crude way by adding another grey layer on top and made it shrink in size. This help create the illusion that the green layer is actually filling up from the bottom. Take a look! http://jsfiddle.net/Lgnk5mnz/2/

HTML add in div cover class:

```
<div id="load-form">
    <div class="load-line"></div>
    <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
<center>
    <div class="percent"></div>
    <div class="asd">2000</div>
</center>
```

CSS add in css for cover class:

```
#load-form {
    width:137px;
    height:87px;
    background:url('http://la2portal.us.lt/status_online_simple.png');
    margin:100px auto 0;
    position:relative;
}
#load-form .load-line {
    background:url('http://la2portal.us.lt/status_online_full.png');
    height:87px;
    width:137px;
    bottom:4px;
    left:6px;
    max-height:87px;
}
#load-form .cover {
    width:137px;
    height:87px;
    background:url('http://la2portal.us.lt/status_online_simple.png');
    margin:-87px auto 0;
    position:relative;
}
```

Finally, animate the cover class and remove animation for load-line.
    $(document).ready(function (e) {

```
    var maxonline = 6000;
    var currentonline = $(this).find('.asd').html();
    var percent = currentonline / maxonline * 100;
    if (percent > 100) percent = 100;
    if (currentonline > maxonline) {
        alert('Its full');
        return;
    }
    $('.cover').animate({
        height: 100 - percent + '%'
    }, 500);
    $('.percent').html(percent + '%')

});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go http://jsfiddle.net/5x275eh1/. I only changed your css

```
    #load-form { width:137px; height:87px; background:url('http://la2portal.us.lt/status_online_simple.png'); margin:100px auto 0;  position:relative; bottom:4px; left:6px;} 
    #load-form .load-line { background:url('http://la2portal.us.lt/status_online_full.png'); height:0; width:137px;  max-height:87px;}
.load-line {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
position:absolute;
    bottom:0px; left:0px;
}
```