# Progress bar from bottom to top controlled by

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create battery indicator for a web app. I use the `progress` bar tag. The problem is that it starts from left to right and i want to be from bottom to top. The second problem is that JavaScript seems to not change anything. How to fix this problems? **Note:** I already read this answers: [Progress Bar Fill Up Bottom-To-Top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155748/progress-bar-fill-up-bottom-to-top)
and this which is not using progress tag:
[How to show a vertical progress bar from bottom to top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422493/how-to-show-a-vertical-progress-bar-from-bottom-to-top)

```js
 navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {
  battery.addEventListener('levelchange', function() {    
   document.getElementById('bat').innerHTML=((battery.level*100));
  })
   document.getElementById('bat').innerHTML=((battery.level*100));
});
```

```css
progress#bat{
    
    position:absolute;
    top:5vh;
    right:5vh;
    height:90vh;
    border:none;
    background-color:black;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class='window' id='battery'>
<p id='batLevel'>BatteryLevel</p>
    <progress max='100' value="22" id='bat'></progress>
</div>
```

Comment: Simplest solution would be rotating it 90° and then adjusting width/height to match your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve the "top to bottom" directional issue for the progress indicator, one solution would be to use CSS transforms in this way:

```
transform:rotate(90deg);
```

That would have the effect of rotating the `<progress/>` element to make the indicator track from top to bottom. You'd then flip the values of width and height to achieve the dimensions of an "upright battery".

Lastly, to cause the progress element to update with changing battery levels, you should set the `value` field on the `bat` element rather than `innerHTML` as you currently are to achieve automatic updates, like so:

```js
navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {

  battery.addEventListener('levelchange', function() {    
  
    /* Apply battery.level * 100 to value field to cause 
       bat element to update as expected */
    document.getElementById('bat').value = battery.level * 100;
  });
  
  /* Apply battery.level * 100 to value field to cause 
     bat element to update as expected */
  document.getElementById('bat').value = battery.level * 100;
});
```

```css
progress#bat{
    
    position:absolute;
    top:5rem;
    left:1rem;
    border:none;
    background-color:black;
    color:red;
    
    transform:rotate(90deg); /* rotation flips 
                perception of width and height */
                
    height:4rem; /* height appears to be width */
    width:9rem;  /* width appears to be height */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <progress max='100' value="12" id='bat'></progress>
</div>
```